# Does Selenium have a way to wait for AngularJS as Protractor do?

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, protractor, browser-automation

Protractor has a method to wait for the AngularJS loading:

```
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Can Selenium simulate this method without Protractor? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that all protractor testing is done via Selenium it is possible. In general you have to wait for all outstanding http requests to complete and then notify/callback your code. It can be done by running JavaScript code in Selenium (browser.execute_script).

Here is the source code for JS part: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/c94f678cfbe142dcb88ef13610d850d60b5e1ccc/lib/clientsidescripts.js